# Exporting bugs out of Jira and into TFS as Work Items

Tags: tfs, jira

Can anyone point me at a half decent tool/method to do this for me? I'm currently playing with TestCaseMigratorPlus and manipulating Jira output but it's not really there.

Comment: Is this a one-off conversion or part of a regular synchronization. The latter probably has to deal with merge conflicts. ~Matt

Comment: it's a one off (that's got to be done for multiple projects)

Comment: ok, I accomplished this from Team Explorer using the "New Items with Microsoft Excel..." CnP and publishing from the spreadsheet to TFS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished this from Team Explorer using the "New Items with Microsoft Excel...", some reordering of columns via 'Team' in the ribbon, a CnP and then publishing from the spreadsheet to TFS.